# Google Calendar не запрашивает права

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar

В одном проекте отрылась веб-страница с запросом прав и сохранился токен, во втором — отладчик просто зависает.

Код взаимодействия с Google Calendar API брал с [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet).

```
UserCredential credential;

var appData = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\";

using (var stream =
    new FileStream(appData + "client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var credPath = appData + "calendar-dotnet.json";

    // Вот перед этим зависает
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
```

Есть подозрение, что токен выдаётся только один раз.